# java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index

Tags: java, sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a SQL query which I want to use to count components into table.

```
private DCDataObj dc;

    public class DCDataObj
    {

        private int datacenter;             //  Datacenters
        ..............

        public DCDataObj(int datacenter............)
        {
            this.datacenter = datacenter;
            ...............
        }

        public int getDatacenter()
        {
            return datacenter;
        }

        public void setDatacenter(int datacenter)
        {
            this.datacenter = datacenter;
        }

        ............
    }

ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(1) AS CNT FROM COMPONENTSTATS CS, COMPONENTTYPE CT "
        + " WHERE CS.COMPONENTTYPEID = CT.COMPONENTTYPEID AND CT.COMPONENTTYPEID IN ( "
        + " ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, " //  10
        + " ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, " //  20
        + " ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, " //  30
        + " ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ) " //  40
        + " GROUP BY CT.NAME ORDER BY CT.NAME");

ps.setInt(1, 1000);
...............

ResultSet result = ps.executeQuery();
            while (result.next())
            {

                dc = new DCDataObj(
                        result.getInt(1),
                        ...............
```

Here is the complete source code: http://pastebin.com/YMvqBPpV

I get this error message: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index

Is this design problem or the problem is into the SQL query?

Comment: Are you getting the error at `ps.setInt` or `result.getInt`?

Comment: The full stacktrace should show you the line on which the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

I saw your full source code and you have a bunch of `result.getInt(INDEX)`. Since you are only doing `SELECT COUNT(1)`, there is only one column, so for any value of `INDEX` other than 1, the `getInt()` will fail.

Change your query to `SELECT <LIST> ...` where `LIST` is a comma separated list of column names from which you want to retrieve values.

Comment: There is no "correct" query, what is it you want your query to return?

Comment: I want the query to return the number of each component.

Comment: Then why are you creating a `new DCDataObj(...)` object after your query. You should just be creating an `int` as `int count = result.getInt(1);`

Comment: Yes but I want to fill the Java Object with the number of each component. With one SQL query I want to get the number of each component

Comment: Your class for that Object doesn't have a field for count. You're going to have to store the count differently.

Comment: Especially on a join, you are correct. The alternative is to write out the name of each column from which you want to retrieve a value.